# How do I push individual array items into another array with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a post call that returns JSON in one of two ways:

```
$json1 = '{"found":1,"email":"email1@domain.com","error":"","rd":"email2@domain.com"}';
$json2 = '{"found":1,"email":"email1@domain.com,email2@domain.com","error":"","rd":"email3@domain.com,email4@domain.com"}';
```

In the first, the `email` and `rd` parameters each only have one email address. In the second, those same two parameters have multiple recipients each.

I need to take the emails from each parameter and add it to an array that already exists:

```
$recipients = array('support@domain.com');
```

I can get it to work with the `$json1` variable using the following code:

```
array_push($recipients, $obj->{'rd'}, $obj->{'email'});
```

The second JSON option is posted more rarely, but I still need the same code to work for both instances. And currently, if I use the above code with the second JSON data it returns this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => support@sculpturehospitality.com
    [1] => email3@domain.com,email4@domain.com
    [2] => email1@domain.com,email2@domain.com
)
```

Which has multiple emails in the same parameter.  Does anyone have any insight on how I can separate the emails within each array item?

A working example:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/24c4a1eaea98566b65cd36e221dd1f185e820ea6

Comment: `explode` items by ','

Comment: Just a side-note. I personally prefer setting the `assoc flag = true` like this `json_decode($json_string, TRUE);` so that your objects are converted to arrays and you can work with syntax like `$obj['email']` rather than `$obj->{'email'}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) your property by a comma and add them to the array, e.g.

```
$recipients = array_merge($recipients, explode(",", $obj->rd)
                                     , explode(",", $obj->email) /*,  ... */);
```

Also note, that I now use [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) instead of [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php), since you don't have a single value anymore, but an array with the new elements:

#### [`array_push():`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

```
//Single value
$array = ["First element"];
$singleValue = "Second element";

array_push($array, $singleValue);
```

output:

```
Array( [0] => First element [1] => Second element)
```

```
//Array
$array = ["First element"];
$secondArray= ["Second element", "And third element"];

array_push($array, $secondArray);
```

output:

```
Array( [0] => First element [1] => Array( [0] => Second element [1] => And third element))
```

#### [`array_merge():`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
//Single value
$array = ["First element"];
$singleValue = "Second element";

$array = array_merge($array, $singleValue);
```

output:

> Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array

```
//Array
$array = ["First element"];
$secondArray= ["Second element", "And third element"];

$array = array_merge($array, $secondArray);
```

output:

```
Array( [0] => First element [1] => Second element [2] => And third element)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I did try the exploding, but I left it as `array_push` which was useless for me! I will accept the answer when I can!

Comment: @TomNolan Updated my answer with an example to show what happens with a single value / array and `array_push()` / `array_merge()`

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP's function explode().

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

`$emailPieces = explode(",", [string_with_multiple_emails]);`

`$emailPieces` will contains an array consisting of each email address provided in `rd` string.